# Visual Studio find numbers and replace with increment of 1 using Regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2012, replace

I have lines of code like this:

```
A[1]
B[2]
C[3]
D[4]
E[5]
F[6]
G[7]
H[8]
I[9]
J[10]
K[11]
.
.
.
```

Now, how can I find and replace all these integers with their incremented number using Regular Expressions so that the result would be like this:

```
A[2]
B[3]
C[4]
D[5]
E[6]
F[7]
G[8]
H[9]
I[10]
J[11]
K[12]
.
.
.
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to do this use `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace()` which takes a callback.